# <query>.loading will not change to true

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

What are the possible reasons for query being stuck on loading = true (networkStatus = 1)?

I cannot get a query result on refetch and cannot log 'called2'

```
graphql(_stepQuery, {
    name: 'stepQuery',
    options: ({goalDocId}) => ({
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      variables: {
        goalDocId
      }
    })
  }
)

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let stepIdsFromServer
    if (nextProps.currentGoalSteps.length > this.props.currentGoalSteps.length)   {
      console.log('called')
      this.props.stepQuery.refetch()
      console.log('this.props', this.props)
      console.log('nextProps',nextProps)
      if (!nextProps.stepQuery.loading) {
      // console.log('nextProps.stepQuery.allSteps', nextProps.stepQuery.allSteps)
          console.log('called2')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks quite dangerous for a infinite loop.

First the `refetch` function is a Promise, so you will not be able to know the correct query state right after the call for refetching. You would need to go on in the `.then` function. See [refetch Api](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/reference/index.html#ObservableQuery%5C.refetch).

Second the query in the end is executed inside the `graphql` wrapper Component. So you should not check the loading state and refetch in the `componentWillReceiveProps` function, Because when the query is executed again the whole component is instantiated again and will enter the `componentWillReceiveProps` function with resetted states and so on.

If you need some kind of search, i suggest you use a mutation as a workaround (using `withApollo` wrapper and in the `componentWillReceiveProps` you call this.props.client("MUTATION")), because this will not render the whole component.